# X position of Elements within a div that you need to scroll because of overflow

Tags: javascript, html

background info:

The page I am working on uses keyboard shortcuts, and when you press down a certain key, whatever element is sitting under the mouse highlights...simple enough, just check the bounds of the possible elements to see if the mouse is sitting above one.

The problem is that in a certain area of the page there is a div that only has the visible height of about 350px, but has an overflow area that can be any size. The div must be scrolled to access the overflow items.

When you scroll into the overflow of the div, to properly gather an elements X/Y position would I also need to subtract the amount of overflow has been scrolled?

I've been stuck on this for awhile, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for element.scrollHeight and element.scrollWidth values?

Comment: You could try [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), it would get you the topmost element at a specific coordinate without much fuzz

Comment: jeff I was wondering if that would solve my problem, subtracting the scrollHeight I guess it would be so yes.   @adeneo it sounds like elementFromPoint's purpose is exactly what I am doing.  I made my own collision detection previously just checking the if the mouse is within  x && x + width  && y && y + width   but I ran into problems with the overflow div. I'm going to give elementFromPoint a try right now.  Looks promising because it is compatible with old IE and that is a requirement right now.

Comment: @adeneo elementFromPoint seems like it works exactly like my own custom version, I tried a quick test to just console.log out what elementFromPoint returns and it gets a dom object every time except when I scroll down in the same overflow div, it returns null.   All elements in this div are appended with jquery.  The visible ones are appended onload and the overflow as you scroll down, is this where the trouble is being caused? does elementFromPoint only get the elements on load?

Comment: if anyone ends up with my issue, the answer was to subtract the scrollTop of the overflow div from the element Y.  Thanks to anyone who thought about a possible solution.